# have difficulties / have problems / have troubles / be struggling

Tags: phrase-meaning

If there are some differencies in these sentences, please, explain it. I think all versions are interchangeable in this context. Only the last one means that the end result will be negative, isn't it? There is an indefinite end result in other sentences.

> I **have difficulties** with physics, chemistry and maths.
>
> I **have problems** with physics, chemistry and maths.
>
> I **have troubles** with physics, chemistry and maths.
>
> I **am struggling** with physics, chemistry and maths.

Comment: They are not interchangeable without loss of meaning. That's the thing - English doesn't consist of identical but separate words. Each word has its own flavor -- for example, the strongest word used here is *struggling*. Also, NONE of the words mean that the end result must be negative.

Comment: @FeliniusRex, It's from Collins dictionary: If a person or organization **is struggling**, they are **likely to fail in** what they are doing, even though they might be trying very hard. ---> the end result highly likely will be negative.

Comment: You are right that the end result is indefinite in all the terms. But they aren't interchangeable. The terms denote different levels of difficulties. Struggling refers to a relatively higher level of difficulty as compared to other terms in the example.

Comment: @Sergey Yes, you are right. **Struggling** means that they are **likely** to fail. However, that does not mean that they **will** fail. In other words, a negative result is not guaranteed. That's what I was getting at.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Felinius said, the phrases aren't completely interchangeable. You could order them based on their relative strength, and I'd say, from softest to strongest:

1. I have difficulties with physics, chemistry and maths.
2. I have trouble with physics, chemistry and maths.
3. I have issues with physics, chemistry and maths.
4. I have problems with physics, chemistry and maths.
5. I am struggling with physics, chemistry and maths.

I don't believe the last one implies the result will be negative, but it seems to indicate the most dire situation. I'll say that "struggling" sounds very much like they are trying hard, though the others don't invoke the same feeling.